# How to display related rows from different unique ID on a same line in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Due to different decisions, it was not able to have multiple, small data models and we are having one large, multi table relationship (many-to-many) model - also we have limited options to modify or alter the model.

As you can see from the below image, in my example, I have multiple columns coming from two different table. For the example, you can see a repair flow, which is containing five different events for the same product. Each part of the flow is under different Repair ID but the events that are coming after the Diagnosis (1st event) having the Initial Repair ID, so that we can link the full flow together (for the same product).

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to display the data on one line, as all the Event Types are related to the same Initial Repair ID:

[image]

My question is how can I achieve to have a PBI table visual which follows the structure of the second picture? To have all the repairs (different event types) for the same product on the same line and a new row would mean a completely differnet product.

Comment: So `table1` has an `Initial Repair ID` column? Or how are `table1` and `table2` related? One approach comes to mind is to add a "Rank/Index" column to the `table1` so that each event is ordered sequential for each `Initial Repaid ID`. Then use that column for the Matrix Column, with `Repair ID`, `Event Type`, and `Completed Date` as the Matrix Values.

Comment: Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hjPM.png

Comment: The two table is linked based on an additional third field in both table, e.g. table1.'service id' = table2.'service id'. In our case let's have it as 'service id' = 1234. My issue with the above solution is that sometimes, for each 'Event Type' I need to retrieve additional fields from different table.  For example, for 'Event Type' = Repair I would like to see xyz from table3 but I don't want to display this next to 'Event Type' = Testing, and then for 'Event Type' = Testing, I would like to display zyx from table4 but only next to it, not for the other 'Event Type's.

Comment: You can handle that with a Measure and a `SWITCH` statement, this measure will be your fourth column. Bottom line, each row will always have the same number of columns (the values can be empty). Otherwise rethink if displaying this in this way is the right way.

Comment: Or you could have just the one column/value like "12345 | Repair | something else | 2024-01-01"